# StackOverflow Exception occured when creating a class of List

Tags: c#, wpf, list, xaml, stack

I have a class like this :

```
class FontSize
{
    List<int> fontSizeList = new List<int>(new int[] { 10, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90 });
    public List<int> GetList()
    {
        return fontSizeList;
    }
}
```

when i want to call it in other file i call the class with

```
AssetText.FontFamily fontFamily = new AssetText.FontFamily();
```

and i can get the value from this code :

```
List<string> fontFamilyList = fontFamily.GetList();
```

There is no exception so far. But when i need something from another (AssetList.xaml.cs)

```
public partial class EditText : Window
    {
        AssetText.FontFamily fontFamily = new AssetText.FontFamily();
        AssetText.FontSize fontSize = new AssetText.FontSize();
        AssetText.FontStyle fontStyle = new AssetText.FontStyle();
        AssetText.ScrollSpeed scrollSpeed = new AssetText.ScrollSpeed();
        AssetText.ScrollDirection scrollDirection = new AssetText.ScrollDirection();

        AssetList assetList = new AssetList();

        public EditText()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            AssetListData selectedItem = assetList.getSelectedItem();

            List<string> fontFamilyList = fontFamily.GetList();
            List<int> fontSizeList = fontSize.GetList();
            List<string> fontStyleList = fontStyle.GetList();
            List<double> scrollSpeedList = scrollSpeed.GetList();
            List<string> scrollDirectionList = scrollDirection.GetList();

            //Values of ComboBoxes
            fontFamily_ComboBox.ItemsSource = fontFamilyList;
            fontSize_ComboBox.ItemsSource = fontSizeList;
            fontStyle_ComboBox.ItemsSource = fontStyleList;
            scrollSpeed_ComboBox.ItemsSource = scrollSpeedList;
            scrollDirection_ComboBox.ItemsSource = scrollDirectionList;

            fontFamily_ComboBox.SelectedValue = selectedItem.textFontFamily;
            fontSize_ComboBox.SelectedValue = selectedItem.textFontSize;
            fontStyle_ComboBox.SelectedValue = selectedItem.textFontStyle;
            scrollSpeed_ComboBox.SelectedValue = selectedItem.textScrollSpeed;
            scrollDirection_ComboBox.SelectedValue = selectedItem.textScrollDirection;
        }
    }
```

Then the StackOverflow Exception is occured in the `FontSize` class. I have no idea what happen to this code, can someone explain?

**EDIT** I tried to use debug, and the debugger keep looping in this section :

```
AssetText.FontFamily fontFamily = new AssetText.FontFamily();
AssetText.FontSize fontSize = new AssetText.FontSize();
AssetText.FontStyle fontStyle = new AssetText.FontStyle();
AssetText.ScrollSpeed scrollSpeed = new AssetText.ScrollSpeed();
AssetText.ScrollDirection scrollDirection = new AssetText.ScrollDirection();

AssetList assetList = new AssetList();
```

**EDIT 2**
I tried to make the code like @cubicle-jockey suggested, and the Exception is called in Break Mode, a new window opened and said that the application is in break mode. This is my first exp getting that error, i have no idea at all

**EDIT 3**
as @peter mention that there might be something that creating new EditText, maybe this is something relevant. I have this code in AssetList.xaml.cs

```
public void GridContextMenu_ItemClick(object sender, Telerik.Windows.RadRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem item = (e.OriginalSource as RadMenuItem).DataContext as MenuItem;
    typeValue = ((AssetListData)AssetList_GridView.SelectedItem).assetType;
    switch (item.Text)
    {
        case "Edit Asset":
            if (typeValue == "abc")
            {
                editText.Show();
                this.Close();
                break;
            }
            else if (typeValue == "aaa")
            {
                editGraphic.Show();
                this.Close();
                break;
            }
            else if (typeValue == "bbb")
            {
                editVideo.Show();
                this.Close();
                break;
            }
            else if (typeValue == "xxx")
            {
                editLiveVideo.Show();
                this.Close();
                break;
            }
            break;
        case "Delete Asset":
            this.AssetList_GridView.Items.Remove(this.AssetList_GridView.SelectedItem);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to post actual code, none of this makes sense,  nor does it seem to relate to each other. You have a class FontSize, which you don't use in any subsequent code fragments, yet you want us to help you find out why a StackOverflowException is thrown when it's used.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt wait, i will copy it

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. Where do you get the exception in this code?

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt in `List<int> fontSizeList = new List<int>(new int[] { 10, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90 });`

Comment: Are you sure that this line: `List<int> fontSizeList = fontSize.GetList();` couses this exception?

Comment: @Marcin please check the **EDIT** it keeps looping there, but when the exception occured, it move to this line : `List<int> fontSizeList = new List<int>(new int[] { 10, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90 });`

Comment: Try to comment whole other code leave only this code with fontSize and check i if still generate exception

Comment: What is `AssetText`?  If it's a static class, does it have a static constructor?

Comment: hi @Cubicle.Jockey i tried your suggestion, please check **EDIT 2**

Comment: Are you use default constructor for FontSize, FontFamily, FontStyle, ScrollSpeed, AssetList ? Something must have been causing this looping

Comment: @dbc AssetText is folder

Comment: Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it is impossible to provide an answer. That said, based on your description of the debugging results, it's clear that you have something that is creating a new `EditText` window over and over recursively. I.e. something about creating the `EditText` window causes some code to want to create yet another. Edit the question with a good code example if you can't find the problem yourself and want an answer.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I dont even know what causes this problem, but yes in AssetList i have something that might open the EditText. i will edit it soon

Comment: @Mirza as I said it wasn't a solution to your issue. I was stating that you are instantiating that list in a weird way. There is no need to create and array to then pass into the list. You can just use the Collection Initializer format.

Comment: The precise point where a `StackOverflow Exception` occurs is often not the problem: it's just one or more levels below some other recursive call that caused the problem. Set a breakpoint and step through your code, you'll soon find the loop.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Fair enough I forgot about that. I will remove to not confuse anyone.

Comment: @Mirza: please read [mcve] again, to understand what kind of code example is needed. The most important point there is that your code example needs to be **minimal** (i.e. include _no_ code that is not _absolutely necessary_ to reproduce the problem) and **complete** (i.e. can be compiled and run as-is, without the need to add anything to it).

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, i debug it myself and found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

I have :

```
EditText editText = new EditText();
```

inside my partial class in AssetList.xaml.cs that causes loop when i call `AssetList` in EditText.xaml.cs So i moved it to a method where it needed.

Thanks for everyones help!